# Google Spreadsheet #Value! Error

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I am developing a reading lesson plan template using a Google spreadsheet. I am stuck! I used the following formula:

```
=query(A2:C;"select A where B='"&Plans!A9:B9&"' AND C='"&Plans!H2&"'")
```

to populate drop-lists of education standards. All my data validation criteria seems to be correct, but I cannot get data to populate my 3rd drop-list. Instead I get the message 'Invalid cell contents validation'

My spreadsheet can be viewed at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmawmBcNyfAbdEs0WU5NYktYcTQyVUhZZ0hhcXdlN1E&usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I removed the :B9 from the data range and now it works!